# How to convert *.tex with references *.bib to *.docx

Tags: bibliographies, conversion, pandoc, msword

I have a *.tex document with references *.bib witten on overleaf. I want to convert this document to *.docx with references. I have used pandoc tools as below:

```
pandoc -s main.tex -o document.docx
```

The problem is I get jus the text without references. Is it possible to generate also the references? 
 example:

***.tex**

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\section{The First Section}
\label{S:1}

Maecenas \cite{Smith:2012qr} fermentum \cite{Smith:2013jd} urna ac sapien tincidunt lobortis. Nunc feugiat faucibus varius. Ut sed purus nunc. Ut eget eros quis lectus mollis pharetra ut in tellus. Pellentesque ultricies velit sed orci pharetra et fermentum lacus imperdiet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse commodo ultrices mauris, condimentum hendrerit lorem condimentum et. Pellentesque urna augue, semper et rutrum ac, consequat id quam. Proin lacinia aliquet justo, ut suscipit massa commodo sit amet. Proin vehicula nibh nec mauris tempor interdum. Donec orci ante, tempor a viverra vel, volutpat sed orci.



\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample.bib}


\end{document}
```

***.bib**

```
@BOOK{Smith:2012qr,
    title = {{B}ook {T}itle},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, J.~M. and Jones, A.~B.},
    year = {2012},
    edition = {7th},
}

@ARTICLE{Smith:2013jd,
    author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
    title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
    journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-456},
    number = {52},
    month = {March},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}
```

Comment: I think we can use latex2rtf with -b option

Comment: Here's an example of how to do it: [pandoc converting tex to docx with references - not enclosed in parentheses / brackets](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/119636)  And are you using `biblatex`? It would be helpful to attach a sample minimal document of what you're doing.

Comment: `tex4ht` can compile your problem with no problems. it can create `odt`, which can be read by Word. Try `mk4ht oolatex sample.tex`, `bibtex sample`, `mk4ht oolatex sample.tex`

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks, I do it with pandoc

Answer (score 1):

Download ieee.csl from [ieee.csl](http://pandoc.org/demo/ieee.csl) to get IEEE biblograpy style and run this command

```
pandoc -s main.tex --bibliography=main.bib --csl=ieee.csl -o main.docx
```

Comment: @AlanMunn, I don't look for pandoc solution only. I look for something that works

Comment: @AlanMunn, I include a minimal sample and I need IEEEtran style like [1], [2] not ()

Comment: +1 I'm glad you worked out a solution. I've deleted my other comments.